# Rails 2.3.2, wrong date, system date is correct

Tags: ruby, datetime, date, localization

```
ruby-1.8.6-p399 :005 > Date.today
 => Wed, 24393 Dec 2135 

ruby-1.8.6-p399 :006 > DateTime.now
 => Wed, 24393 Dec 2135 17:07:09 +0100

wopi@wopi-desktop:~/work/trunk$ date
Mi 2. Feb 17:08:46 CET 2011
```

What's wrong ?

https://gist.github.com/807916

Comment: What time does your database return?

Comment: try a newer ver of ruby(just for diagnosis)? will u get the same problem?

Comment: Anna, my database time is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you get with: Time.at(0) ?

Should be 1969...

What do you get with Time.now?

The date objects come from the date class, which inherits from the time class:

http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html

Other helpful methods to test could be there. Try doing straight ruby to see if it's a problem with your rails setup or with ruby. You should be able to trace the specific place where this goes wrong.